# Hibernate Search Adding Correlation Id to the request

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

I have been trying to add correlation ID in hibernate search . Tried creating custom HTTP client configure as given in the documentation. But It's not working .

```
@Configuration
public class HttpClientConfigurer implements ElasticsearchHttpClientConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configure(ElasticsearchHttpClientConfigurationContext context) {
        System.out.println("Setting the correlationId");
        MDC.put("correlationId", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        System.out.println("The correlationId is set");
        HttpAsyncClientBuilder clientBuilder = context.clientBuilder();
        clientBuilder.setMaxConnPerRoute( 7 );
        clientBuilder.addInterceptorFirst( (HttpResponseInterceptor) (request, httpContext) -> {
            System.out.println("Checkpoint 2");
        } );
        clientBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

Added this in the properties :

```
elasticsearch.search.backend.client.configurer = com.broadridge.basmsp.configuration.HttpClientConfigurer
```

Need to add correlation Id here in the request  :

```
2022-09-26 12:51:33.132 TRACE [     ] 11712 --- [port thread - 1] o.h.search.elasticsearch.request         : HSEARCH400093: Executed Elasticsearch HTTP POST request to 'http://localhost:9200' with path 'read', query parameters {from=0, size=25, track_total_hits=true} and 1 objects in payload in 15ms. Response had status 200 'OK'. Request body: <{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"bool":POST}...},"hits":{"total":{"value":0,"relation":"eq"},"hits":[]}}>
```

Comment: I probably won't be able to help you, because I think your question relates to tracing somehow and I don't know much about that. But if you want to get answers, you should probably explain a bit more: which technology you're using (what's that "correlationId", what's that MDC thingy?), and what you tried exactly (System.out.println hardly qualifies as an attempt).

Comment: MDC is Mapped Diagnostic Context in SL4J  and adds correlationId to the logs.  So my attempt was to add correlationId to the logs with or without MDC . SOP was to test if the code is being reached. Which seems to be unreachable. Followed the steps mention here. But the code is completely unreachable.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#backend-elasticsearch-configuration-http-client

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration propery is invalid:

```
elasticsearch.search.backend.client.configurer
```

Should be:

```
hibernate.search.backend.client.configurer
```

Comment: hibernate.search.backend.client.configurer . I tried using this also 

hibernate.search.backend.client.configurer = class:org.hibernate.search.documentation.backend.elasticsearch.client.HttpClientConfigurer